# preg_replace не заменятт

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, я ожидаю: `news/view/sport/22`

А вижу: `http://localhost/test2.2/index.php/news/view/sport/22`

Код:

```
$uri = "http://localhost/test2.2/index.php/news/sport/22";
$uriPattern = "/news\/([\w]+)\/([\d]+)/";
$path = 'news/view/$1/$2';
echo preg_replace($uriPattern, $path, $uri) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` заменяет подстроку, но не отрезает то, что было до нее. Я бы сначала от `$uri` отрезал все лишнее, а потом уже делал замену. Замена делается правильно.
Отрезать можно так

```
$arr = explode('index.php/', $uri);
```

вернет массив, вам нужен второй элемент.

Comment: спасибо большое